# ReformAlign executable not stable.

Tags: makefile, executable

I have compiled and executable (ReformAlign) from a makefile, however, on launching it, it opens and closes immediately.

Is there something I failed to do or should do to enable work properly. 
Any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> on launching it, it opens and closes immediately

You don't offer much context.  I suspect by *launching it*, you mean clicking on an icon in Windows.  The program runs and, because it's very small, finishes immediately.  The window it runs in barely shows on your screen, if at all.

If that's the case, start **cmd.exe**, and run your program from the command line.  That will give you a chance to see its output.

Comment: It is actually a command line executable. It opens briefly and shuts down.

Comment: I have tried running the program on cmd.exe but it gives an error message; RefromAlign.exe/ReformAlign is not recognized and an internal or external command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to run the executable from the command window.

On Windows: start **cmd.exe** then inside the cmd go to the directory where your ReformAlign.exe file is saved. You can change directories with the `cd` command.
After that you can simply type the name of your executable and it should start running.

Example:
`C:\Users\Nabi> cd YourFileDirectory\MaybeSomeSubdirectory`
Press Enter, then type the name of your *.exe file.
`C:\Users\Nabi\YourFileDirectory\MaybeSomeSubdirectory> ReformAlign.exe` 
Again press Enter, and your file should start.

Comment: Thank you so much; it worked. However I got an error message: **Error: Input file not defined. Please type ReformAlign -h for usage instructions. *************ReformAlign will now terminate.

Comment: It seems that it's nothing wrong anymore with executing the file. I don't know the ReformAlign program, but it seems to me that you have to define an input file, so that the program can work properly. I will take a look at the program this evening, assuming it's this one: [ReformAlign](http://evol.bio.lmu.de/_statgen/software/reformalign/)

Comment: I tried the programm but i couldn't figure out the problem, sorry can't help you any further

Comment: @ V. L.Thank you so much for your help. I can not really figure out what is wrong with the program. I input my unaligned sequences and initial alignment ( all in fasta format as required), however, it gives an error message:       Unable to open alignment file GambianClX.  ReformAlign does not contain and aligner I do not know if I have to link it to an aligner and if so how. It is not specified in the instructions. Programming is not my thing.

Comment: ReformAlign is supposed to be used with your favourite aligner but I do not how to.

Comment: @ V.L. Please do you mind if I ask you for some help? If you had looked at the program there happen to be three files that were not used in compiling the executable ReformAlign.exe, these files are; Tokenizer.cpp, Tokenizer.h, TypeDefinitions.h and Utils.h. I do not know if these files have some additional use with the executable.

Comment: @ V.L. Thank you so much. It is okay now. All I had to do was input ReformAlign.exe -i Sequences.fasta -o Output.fasta -a Init_Align.fasta; then if I needed the verbose mode turn it on with -v

Answer (score 0):

ReformAlign has no aligners but reforms previously align sequences (from a target aligner). Just input; ReformAlign.exe i- Sequences.fasta -o Output.fasta -a Init_align.fasta
were Sequences.fasta is your unaligned sequences, output.fasta =RefromAlign output and Init_Align.fasta your previously or initially aligned sequences. The initially alignes sequences should contianed gaps else ReformAlign may return output which is not different from the unaligned sequences.